# Is a Lebesgue measurable set always the UNION of a $G_{\delta}$ set and a set of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

A known fact is that a Lebesgue measurable set is a $G_{\delta}$ set minus a set of measure zero. But I am not sure if it is always the union of a $G_{\delta}$ set and a set of measure zero.

Comment: Take a meagre $F_{\sigma}$ of full measure.